# Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> nesting that works with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have read about 30 Stack Overflow questions, and about 20 blogs and cannot find my answer. That said, I am sure the answer I require is out there so if you know of it please point it out (please note the last paragraph/sentence about answers that do not fit my requirement). Thanks!

I am persisting instances of classes that have a similar shape to:

```
public class Data {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Container {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Currently queries are written to find Containers via an abstraction layer that requires a Lambda Expression accepting a Container and returning bool (predicate). It will not accept IQueryable even though Entity Framework 5 is the ORM of choice.

My task is to present an API surface based around Lambda Expressions that accept the Data type. I cannot change the abstraction layer (I must pass a predicate that accepts a Container) so I am trying to convert an expression I receive as:

```
Expression<Func<Data , bool>>
to:
Expression<Func<Container , bool>>
```

I have added an extra method in my repository class like these:

```
public Container Find( Expression<Func<Data , bool>> predicate ) {

    IEnumerable<Container> result = QueryStrategy.Fetch( c => predicate.Compile().Invoke( c.Data ) );

    return result.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

This compliments the existing Find method:

```
public Container Find( Expression<Func<Container , bool>> predicate ) {

    IEnumerable<Container> result = QueryStrategy.Fetch( predicate );

    return result.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

When the former method is used it produces the following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   Invoke(Container.Data)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

I have tried all sorts of things with Expression classes I just can't see a way to map:

```
Expression<Func<Data , bool>>
to:
Expression<Func<Container , bool>>
```

Without using Invoke which is not supported by Entity Framework (but works fine with in memory enumerable data).

Can anybody help me get the above scenario working using Expressions?

I understand that I may be able to use the LinqKit library to solve this, but I really want to solve this problem without bringing in a third party library.

UPDATE: In my effort to present a simplified problem, I have implied (by originally using DbContext in the code sample) that the code would have access to IQueryable and/or be suitable for using LinqKit's AsExpandable(). In reality this is not the case - the repository class is not allowed to use IQueryable or any vendor specific extensions. I have modified the examples above and hopefully this makes things clearer.

***This Issue Is Now Solved***

Comment: Is it a requirement that the filtering of Containers by your Func<Data, bool> expression take place in the database?

Comment: Any particular reason that you don't want a bring in a third-party library? As you mentioned above, LinqKit can handle composing the expressions in the way you want; doing it without LinqKit would probably require duplicating a lot of its functionality.

Comment: One reason is that I think the solution is only going to require a few lines whereby the Expression is built up correctly. I would only use the library if this was happening in various places. The other thing I should add (and I will update the question to make this clearer) is that the repository class I am working with is designed to not know anything about Entity Framework or Databases etc. IQueryable is not presented to this layer and so AsExpandable() should not either because it exists to prop up Entity Framework.

Comment: Shame I have an answer for this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031493/how-can-i-transform-this-linq-expression/19032146#19032146

Comment: @Aron The solution is below - but yes, you do something similar also using an ExpressionVisitor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem after 4 hours of reading/tinkering with Expressions (amazing technology).

I have put this class together (it is not polished or final but shows how it was achieved):

```
class ParameterRewriter<TTarget , TSource> : ExpressionVisitor {

    private ParameterExpression Source;
    private MemberExpression Target;

    public Expression<Func<TTarget , bool>> Rewrite( Expression<Func<TSource , bool>> predicate , Expression<Func<TTarget , TSource>> propertyNameExpression ) {

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter( typeof( TTarget ) );

        var propertyName = ( propertyNameExpression.Body as MemberExpression ).Member.Name;

        Source = predicate.Parameters.Single();
        Target = Expression.PropertyOrField( parameter , propertyName );

        var body = Visit( predicate.Body );

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTarget , bool>>(
            body ,
            parameter
        );

    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter( ParameterExpression node ) {

        if ( node == Source ) {
            return Target;
        }

        return base.VisitParameter( node );

    }

}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
var parameterRewriter = new ParameterRewriter<Container , Data>();
Expression<Func<Data , bool>> dataPredicate = d => ( d.Id == 1 );
var containerPredicate = parameterRewriter.Rewrite( dataPredicate , c => c.Data );
```

In theory one should be able to traverse deeper relationships by examining propertyNameExpression but I have had enough for today.

I can now see that the SQL Entity Framework has generated for each flavour of query is identical:

========================

```
Expression<Func<Container , bool>> p = c => c.Data.Id == 1

SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[Data_Id] AS [Data_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Container] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Data_Id]
```

========================

```
Expression<Func<Data , bool>> p = d => d.Id == 1

SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[Data_Id] AS [Data_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Container] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Data_Id]
```

========================

Comment: @SeanHill Now you tell me! Haha - it is 5.30am here and I could have been sleeping ;)

Answer (score 1):

Join customers with filtered by predicated data, then select customer from result

```
public Container Find(Expression<Func<Data, bool>> predicate ) 
{
    return MyDbContext.Containers
                      .Join(MyDbContext.Containers.Select(c => c.Data)
                                                  .Where(predicate), 
                            c => c.Data.Id,
                            d => d.Id,
                            (c, d) => c)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: There is no MyDbContext.Datas exposed.

Comment: @Jamie `Data` is not entity? Anyway - you can join table to self. I'll update answer

Comment: It is not an Aggregate Root.

Comment: Sorry - I really shouldn't have made this question so Entity Framework focused. It is about using the Expression classes much more than it is about the Entity Framework. It was just that Entity Framework's lack of support for the Invoke Expression was at the heart of the problem but I can see how people think it is a query issue (I cannot query - only supply a predicate).