# How can I transform this linq expression?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

Say I have an entity that I want to query with ranking applied:

```
public class Person: Entity
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

In my query I have the following:

```
Expression<Func<Person, object>> orderBy = x => x.Name;

var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

var keyword = "term";
var startsWithResults = dbContext.People
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(keyword))
    .Select(x => new {
        Rank = 1,
        Entity = x,
    });
var containsResults = dbContext.People
    .Where(x => !startsWithResults.Select(y => y.Entity.Id).Contains(x.Id))
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword))
    .Select(x => new {
        Rank = 2,
        Entity = x,
    });

var rankedResults = startsWithResults.Concat(containsResults)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Rank);

// TODO: apply thenby ordering here based on the orderBy expression above

dbContext.Dispose();
```

I have tried ordering the results before selecting the anonymous object with the `Rank` property, but the ordering ends up getting lost. It seems that linq to entities discards the ordering of the separate sets and converts back to natural ordering during both `Concat` and `Union`.

What I think I may be able to do is dynamically transform the expression defined in the `orderBy` variable from `x => x.Name` to `x => x.Entity.Name`, but I'm not sure how:

```
if (orderBy != null)
{
    var transformedExpression = ???
    rankedResults = rankedResults.ThenBy(transformedExpression);
}
```

How might I be able to use `Expression.Lambda` to wrap `x => x.Name` into `x => x.Entity.Name`? When I hard code `x => x.Entity.Name` into the `ThenBy` I get the ordering that I want, but the `orderBy` is provided by the calling class of the query, so I don't want to hard-code it in. I have it hardcoded in the example above for simplicity of explanation only.

Comment: Deleted my answer so you can try to reclaim the bounty.  If you would post a follow-up comment once you've awarded it to Aron, I'll re-post my answer in case it helps anyone in the future.  BTW, did you try my solution, and if so, did it work?

Comment: @MikeStrobel thanks I really appreciate this. You can go ahead and repost your answer as a separate, just don't undelete the one you deleted please. I am still waiting on the bounty to be refunded to that I can re-award it.

Comment: Using a strongly typed placeholder class here would have saved a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help. However you are going to have to concrete up the Anonymous type for this to work. My LinqPropertyChain will not work with it, since its going to be difficult to create the `Expression<Func<Anonymous, Person>>` whilst its still Anonymous.

```
Expression<Func<Person, object>> orderBy = x => x.Name;

using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
var keyword = "term";
var startsWithResults = dbContext.People
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(keyword))
    .Select(x => new {
        Rank = 1,
        Entity = x,
    });
var containsResults = dbContext.People
    .Where(x => !startsWithResults.Select(y => y.Entity.Id).Contains(x.Id))
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword))
    .Select(x => new {
        Rank = 2,
        Entity = x,
    });


var rankedResults = startsWithResults.Concat(containsResults)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Rank)
    .ThenBy(LinqPropertyChain.Chain(x => x.Entity, orderBy));

// TODO: apply thenby ordering here based on the orderBy expression above

}

public static class LinqPropertyChain 
{

    public static Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> Chain<TInput, TOutput, TIntermediate>(
        Expression<Func<TInput, TIntermediate>> outter,
        Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TOutput>> inner
        )
    {

        Console.WriteLine(inner);
        Console.WriteLine(outter);
        var visitor = new Visitor(new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>
        {
            {inner.Parameters[0], outter.Body}
        });

        var newBody = visitor.Visit(inner.Body);
        Console.WriteLine(newBody);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, TOutput>>(newBody, outter.Parameters);
    }

    private class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> _replacement;

        public Visitor(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> replacement)
        {
            _replacement = replacement;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (_replacement.ContainsKey(node))
                return _replacement[node];
            else
            {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Figured out a way to do this with less Explicite Generics.

```
Expression<Func<Person, object>> orderBy = x => x.Name;
Expression<Func<Foo, Person>> personExpression = x => x.Person;

var helper = new ExpressionChain(personExpression);
var chained = helper.Chain(orderBy).Expression;


// Define other methods and classes here
public class ExpressionChain<TInput, TOutput>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> _expression; 
    public ExpressionChain(Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
    }

    public Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> Expression { get { return _expression; } }

    public ExpressionChain<TInput, TChained> Chain<TChained>
        (Expression<Func<TOutput, TChained>> chainedExpression)
    {
        var visitor = new Visitor(new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>
        {
            {_expression.Parameters[0], chainedExpression.Body}
        });
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, TOutput>>(newBody, outter.Parameters);
        return new ExpressionChain(lambda);
    }

    private class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> _replacement;

        public Visitor(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> replacement)
        {
            _replacement = replacement;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (_replacement.ContainsKey(node))
                return _replacement[node];
            else
            {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this definitely works. In addition to concreting the anonymous type, I also had to explicitly spell out the generic args to the Chain method. It only worked when I did `.ThenBy(LinqPropertyChain.Chain<ConcreteRanker, object, Person>(x => x.Entity, orderBy))`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're ordering by `Rank` first, and the `Rank` values are identical within each sequence, you should be able to just sort independently and then concatenate.  It sounds like the hiccup here would be that, according to your post, Entity Framework isn't maintaining sorting across `Concat` or `Union` operations.  You should be able to get around this by forcing the concatenation to happen client-side:

```
var rankedResults = startsWithResults.OrderBy(orderBy)
                                     .AsEnumerable()
                                     .Concat(containsResults.OrderBy(orderBy));
```

This should render the `Rank` property unnecessary and probably simplify the SQL queries being executed against your database, and it doesn't require mucking about with expression trees.

The downside is that, once you call `AsEnumerable()`, you no longer have the option of appending additional database-side operations (i.e., if you chain additional LINQ operators after `Concat`, they will use the LINQ-to-collections implementations).  Looking at your code, I don't think this would be a problem for you, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: For the record, I know I could have done this by hitting the database and then concating the results. There are additional db-side operations going on after the sorting -- namely, pagination (`.Skip` and `.Take`), so afaik, I do have to muck with the expression tree before hitting the db.